# JSON.stringify returning empty object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return the position object as a string, with the following code:

```
window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => console.log(JSON.stringify(position)),
      err => console.log(err)
);
```

but the return of the log of the previous code is {}.

if I remove the JSON.stringify the log show the object as expected but not as a string.

Comment: Do you sure the position returned is a string to you can convert with JSON.stringify?

Comment: Always suspect the input. Check `position` is an object.